# ¿Como elminar &nbsp de mis arrays en JS/vueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hola a todos gracias por sus respuestas y comentarios estoy un poco frustrado con esto he intentado borrar el &nbsp que equivale a un espacio en blanco en mi array y no he podido hasta el momento el problema es que estoy usando un pluging en concreto es vue-table-dynamic en su metodo editar la tabla cuando el usuario edita este pluging me rotorntoda la data junto con los valores cambiados el detalle esta en que ya me retorna todo el array y no el dato que se ha cambiado para realizar un trim() y limpiar los espacios, por lo que he pensado directamente en cabiarlo desde el array devuelto.

Este es el array devuelto con el espacio en blanco que quiero limpiar especificamente en apellidos del primer registro.

```
const data = [
                 ['id', 'nombre', 'apellidos', 'edad']
                 [1, 'Juan', 'Cruz Nuñez&nbsp;', '23']
                 [2, 'Nallely', 'Viridiana Herrera', '24']
             ];
```

Lo que quisiera obtener es lo siguiente modificando data:

```
  const data = [
                     ['id', 'nombre', 'apellidos', 'edad']
                     [1, 'Juan', 'Cruz Nuñez;', '23']
                     [2, 'Nallely', 'Viridiana Herrera', '24']
                 ];
```

De ante mano muchas gracias por sus respuestas en la documentación del pluging hay demos con el mismo comportamiento que aquí explico por lo que supongo es un error del mismo.
Si alguien a usado este pluging y solucionado este problema les agradeceria mucho un consejo para solventar el problema, de nuevo muchas gracias.
[vue-table-dynamic](https://github.com/TheoXiong/vue-table-dynamic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías utilizar la [función map en el array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), y reemplazar `&nbsp;` utilizando [la función replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) en los valores de tipo `String`.

```js
const data = [
    ['id', 'nombre', 'apellidos', 'edad'],
    [1, 'Juan', 'Cruz Nuñez&nbsp;', '23'],
    [2, 'Nallely', 'Viridiana Herrera', '24']
];

var formattedData = data.map(function(row) {
    return row.map(function(value) {
        if(typeof value === "string") return value.replace("&nbsp;", "");
        else return value;
    });
});

console.log(formattedData);
```

---

Utlizando [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
const data = [
    ['id', 'nombre', 'apellidos', 'edad'],
    [1, 'Juan', 'Cruz Nuñez&nbsp;', '23'],
    [2, 'Nallely', 'Viridiana Herrera', '24']
];

var formattedData = data.map(row => row.map(value => (typeof value === "string") ? value.replace("&nbsp;", "") : value));

console.log(formattedData);
```